# Setting expiry interval for cache in an entity (eclipselink/JPA 2.0)

Tags: java, caching, eclipselink

Could someone tell me how to make the cache expire in an entity at some regular interval(in Eclipselink/JPA 2.0)? I am trying to use @Cacheable annotation.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
@Entity
@Cache( expiry=360000 )
public class Person {
...
}
```

This will set expiry time for an entity. Expiry time is in milliseconds.
First time when you fetch data from database, it will fire  a query. That entity instance will be cached. But after 6 minutes, this instance will be invalidated but not removed from cache. When it is accessed, it is refreshed from database.
You can also check this : http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Expiration.
For deep knowledge of caching you can refer : http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.in/2013/01/got-cache.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the cache provider. You can set these things in a separate configuration file.

Comment: Do you mean I need to set this in the persistence.xml? Could you please elaborate your answer a bit?

Comment: Since I use Eclipselink, that's my cache provider. I am new to Eclipselink/JPA. Please help me to understand if I am missing something.

Comment: I don't know how exactly to configure the built-in cache in eclipselink, but that's the place to look at. http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_Cache_%28ELUG%29 http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/JPA_2.0/cache_usaged#Section_3.7.1_-_The_shared-cache-mode_element

Comment: and http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_%28ELUG%29#How_to_Use_the_Persistence_Unit_Properties_for_Caching